# Defining clauses as in the C standard document?

Tags: numbering, paragraphs

I am trying to write a document with the same presentation as the C standard document.
Here is the document: [C draft n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

Look at page 256 and the 7.12.4.1 section for example. My question is how to do something equivalent to the clauses "Synopsis", "Description", "Returns" with a bold title, a little vertical space, and a number in the margin ?

Comment: This document is TeX'd - they likely set up an environment to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe not the best way to do it, but it has the desired output.  It is possible to place the first argument in a `verbatim` or `listings` environment, but for clarity I left it out.  It should be further noted that this solution doesn't break things like footnotes, labels, etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}

\newlength{\MarginLength}
\setlength{\MarginLength}{\labelwidth}
\addtolength{\MarginLength}{\labelsep}

\newcommand{\domargin}[1]{%
  \hspace*{-\MarginLength}\makebox[0pt][r]{#1}\hspace*{\MarginLength}}

\newcommand{\defun}[3]{%
  \subsubsection*{Synopsis}\domargin{1}%
  #1%
  \subsubsection*{Desciption}\domargin{2}%
  #2%
  \subsubsection*{Returns}\domargin{3}%
  #3%
}

\begin{document}
\defun{%
  \lipsum[1]
  }{%
  \lipsum[2]
  }{%
  \lipsum[3]
}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]